# how can I change screen resolution with Intel integrated graphics on Atom x6413 processor

Tags: drivers, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I have a new single board computer (iBase IB836F-6413E) which uses the Intel Atom x6413 processor, and I am unable to get any screen resolution other than 1024x768 to work.

My setup is as follows:

- **Board:** iBase IB836F-6413 SBC
- **Processor:** Intel Atom x6413 with integrated Intel UHD Graphics for 10th Gen Intel Processors
- **RAM:** 4GB PC4-3200
- **Storage:** 120GB mSATA SSD
- **Monitor:** Iiyama Prolite XUB3493XQSU. Supports resolutions up to 3440x1440. Connected via Display Port (DP) connector.
- **Power:** 19V DC power supply via DC input connector
- **Keyboard:** Logitech wireless via receiver plugged into USB port
- **Mouse:** Logitech wireless using same wireless receiver as keyboard.
- **Operating System:** Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
- **Linux Kernel:** 5.11.0.

The xrandr command shows the monitor name as default, but I think it should be DP-1, or something similar, since my monitor is connected via the DP connector. See below for xrandr output.

I have tried adding new output modes using xrandr as follows:

```
$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (0x521) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x520
    Timestamp:  140204
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1024x768 (0x521) 59.769MHz *current
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock  58.37KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock  76.00Hz

$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x54e) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
$ sudo xrandr --addmode default "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96
```

The 1920x1080 resolution then shows up in display settings, but nothing changes when I select it.
See screenshot:
[image]

Could it be that the Atom x6413 is too new for the integrated graphics to be supported yet? This chip was launched in Jan 2021.

dmesg on the freshly booted system doesn't appear to show any errors related to the graphics.

The inxi -G command shows:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1024x768~76Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.3
```

The Intel driver: N/A looks suspicious.

lshw -C display shows:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the video output to work correctly?

I have also tried updating the kernel to 5.14.1, and I see the same problem.

I have looked through the dmesg output for both kernel versions (5.11.0 and 5.14.1) and see an oops related to pinctrl_elkhartlake. Maybe this has some relevance to the graphics problems, but it would seem unlikely.
Here is the dmesg output showing the error for kernel version 5.14.1:

```
...
[    0.741662] acpi device:4e: hash matches
[    0.741810] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    0.743163] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2036K
[    0.743723] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2892K
[    0.763189] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 30720k
[    0.764251] Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2036K
[    0.764773] Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1816K
[    0.780290] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    0.780298] Run /init as init process
[    0.780307]   with arguments:
[    0.780315]     /init
[    0.780317]     splash
[    0.780319]   with environment:
[    0.780320]     HOME=/
[    0.780322]     TERM=linux
[    0.780323]     BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.1-051401-generic
[    0.872410] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
[    0.872426] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[    0.872428] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[    0.872431] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[    0.872434] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
[    0.872438] CPU: 2 PID: 174 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G          I       5.14.1-051401-generic #202109030936
[    0.872442] Hardware name:  /, BIOS 5.19 06/22/2021
[    0.872444] RIP: 0010:strcmp+0xc/0x20
[    0.872450] Code: 06 49 89 f8 48 83 c6 01 48 83 c7 01 88 47 ff 84 c0 75 eb 4c 89 c0 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 31 c0 eb 08 48 83 c0 01 84 d2 74 0f <0f> b6 14 07 3a 14 06 74 ef 19 c0 83 c8 01 c3 31 c0 c3 66 90 48 85
[    0.872454] RSP: 0018:ffffa10bc05b7b10 EFLAGS: 00010246
[    0.872457] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffffa10bc05b7ac0
[    0.872459] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffffc007ac93 RDI: 0000000000000000
[    0.872461] RBP: ffffa10bc05b7b38 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[    0.872464] R10: ffff8f37ca2ec000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffc007cc40
[    0.872466] R13: ffffffffc007e0e0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffffffc007e140
[    0.872468] FS:  00007f1339622880(0000) GS:ffff8f384bf00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    0.872471] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    0.872473] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000010d84a000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
[    0.872476] Call Trace:
[    0.872479]  ? intel_pinctrl_get_soc_data+0x67/0xc0
[    0.872484]  intel_pinctrl_probe_by_uid+0x13/0x30
[    0.872488]  platform_probe+0x42/0xa0
[    0.872492]  really_probe+0x1fb/0x400
[    0.872495]  __driver_probe_device+0x109/0x180
[    0.872498]  driver_probe_device+0x23/0x90
[    0.872501]  __driver_attach+0xac/0x1b0
[    0.872503]  ? __device_attach_driver+0xe0/0xe0
[    0.872506]  bus_for_each_dev+0x7c/0xc0
[    0.872509]  driver_attach+0x1e/0x20
[    0.872511]  bus_add_driver+0x135/0x1f0
[    0.872513]  driver_register+0x95/0xf0
[    0.872516]  ? 0xffffffffc0081000
[    0.872519]  __platform_driver_register+0x1e/0x20
[    0.872522]  ehl_pinctrl_driver_init+0x1c/0x1000 [pinctrl_elkhartlake]
[    0.872527]  do_one_initcall+0x46/0x1d0
[    0.872531]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x159/0x2c0
[    0.872535]  do_init_module+0x62/0x290
[    0.872539]  load_module+0xaa8/0xb40
[    0.872543]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xbf/0x120
[    0.872547]  __x64_sys_finit_module+0x18/0x20
[    0.872550]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0xc0
[    0.872554]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
[    0.872558]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
[    0.872561]  ? __x64_sys_read+0x19/0x20
[    0.872565]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
[    0.872568]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
[    0.872572] RIP: 0033:0x7f1339ba489d
[    0.872575] Code: 00 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c3 f5 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[    0.872580] RSP: 002b:00007ffe65f1b308 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[    0.872583] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00005604123a8d70 RCX: 00007f1339ba489d
[    0.872586] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f1339a81ded RDI: 0000000000000005
[    0.872588] RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[    0.872590] R10: 0000000000000005 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f1339a81ded
[    0.872593] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00005604123aa7b0 R15: 00005604123a8d70
[    0.872596] Modules linked in: video(+) fjes(+) pinctrl_elkhartlake(+)
[    0.872603] CR2: 0000000000000000
[    0.872606] ---[ end trace 42d0286ff1ef1c67 ]---
[    0.872608] RIP: 0010:strcmp+0xc/0x20
[    0.872611] Code: 06 49 89 f8 48 83 c6 01 48 83 c7 01 88 47 ff 84 c0 75 eb 4c 89 c0 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 31 c0 eb 08 48 83 c0 01 84 d2 74 0f <0f> b6 14 07 3a 14 06 74 ef 19 c0 83 c8 01 c3 31 c0 c3 66 90 48 85
[    0.872615] RSP: 0018:ffffa10bc05b7b10 EFLAGS: 00010246
[    0.872618] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffffa10bc05b7ac0
[    0.872620] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffffffc007ac93 RDI: 0000000000000000
[    0.872622] RBP: ffffa10bc05b7b38 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[    0.872625] R10: ffff8f37ca2ec000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffc007cc40
[    0.872627] R13: ffffffffc007e0e0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffffffc007e140
[    0.872629] FS:  00007f1339622880(0000) GS:ffff8f384bf00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    0.872632] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    0.872634] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 000000010d84a000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
[    0.872654] fbcon: Taking over console
[    0.872722] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[    0.927847] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
...
```

Comment: Yes, "unclaimed" in layperson's terms means "no driver". Probably it needs an even newer kernel.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have tried updating the kernel, and updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get all resolutions supported by my monitor working by forcing the i915 driver to probe.
i.e. I edited the linux boot command line in the grub config file to be as follows:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.force_probe=4555"
This was in the file:
/etc/default/grub
I then ran sudo update-grub and rebooted, and all the resolutions were shown in display settings and they all worked.
I figured this out by noting that the output from lsmod showed nothing using the i915 module:

```
lsmod | grep i915
i915                 2297856  0
drm_kms_helper        237568  1 i915
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
drm                   548864  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 igb,i915
video                  49152  1 i915
```

Also the output from lspci gave the device details for the device ID of 4555:

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i -A3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4555] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
    Kernel modules: i915
```